# How to align a label respecting linebreaks?

Tags: css, gwt

I'm creating a Label that has an icon on the left, alreay works fine:

```
<g:FlowPanel>
  <g:Image ... />
  <g:InlineLabel styleName="{style.label}" />
</g:FlowPanel>
```

Now I want to limit the width of the `FlowPanel`, so that the label will auto linebreak for long text.
BUT then the broken text will start below the icon. What I want is to start the text with padding to the left like the icon width.

Example, if 'x' is the icon:

```
x my long
text

x my long
  text
```

I'm looking for the 2nd style. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Look at flex table for proper row and column alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Give float:left to img
2. Move the Image Icon to left using (-) minus left-margin
3. Give left-padding for "FlowPanel".

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float:left;` to the css of both the InlineLabel and the Image should make the label text stay as a block and not wrap around the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give left-padding to the panel container and put the image in absolute positioning.